# How can I get the real Emailaddress of a recipient?

Tags: email, exchange-2010, exchange

a user in out Company has 2 mail-addresses on one Exchange-Mailbox. e.g test@... and test1@... the Primary SMTP-address off the Mailbox is test@. If I send a message to test1@, load it using EWS and parse through the TORecipients-Collection there is exactly one emailadress. But the mailaddress EWS gives to me is test@... and not test1@... where I sent the mail.

My problem is, that all mails sent to test@ should be imported in our CRM using my program. All mails sent to test1@... must not be imported. In real life both mailaddresses are from my Boss. One is used for normal purposes the other one is for confidential e.g. from his lawyer.

Does anyone know how I can get the real-emailaddress the message was sent to?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get it via EWS using the InternetMessageHeaders property... But I have an easier solution:

1. Create a new distribution-group, and set it's smtp address to you're boss's second address.
2. Make him the only member of the group.

Messages sent to that dist-group will be delivered to your boss, but the TO: field will show the name/address of the group.